# Three.js Create multiple objects

Tags: javascript, for-loop, three.js

I want to create multiple objects.

```
    var distance = 10;
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff44});

    for(var i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.position.z = distance;
        scene.add(mesh);
        distance += 5;
    };`
```

With this code i create it, but only in one row. I want to create more rows on the back of the first row. Like this image:

[What i want to create - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omijq.png)

I want more cubes on the **Red X** position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xDistance = 50;
var zDistance = 30;
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff44});

//initial offset so does not start in middle.
var xOffset = -80;

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.position.x = (xDistance * i) + xOffset;
            mesh.position.z = (zDistance * j);
            scene.add(mesh);
    }
};
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/yv0sd6dz/)